# Finding patterns in Graph visualization

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, graphs-and-networks

> Please comment me if you think this question is not related to
>   *Mathematica* stack exchange.

I am trying to draw a graph representation of the system shown below

[image]

As you can see, when red line passes the gray region, it split into two red lines. If two red line pass together (2 and 6 at the third grey region), they make a connection. In this system, there are four grey region, so it makes the connection such as,

```
{1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 1 <-> 7, 1 <-> 8, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 2 <-> 7, 
 3 <-> 5, 3 <-> 6, 4 <-> 5}
```

General equation in terms of n (number of gray region) is shown below

```
Manipulate[
 Graph[DeleteCases[
   Flatten[Table[
     If[i <= n && j <= n + 1 - i, i <-> n + j], {i, 1, 2 n}, {j, 1, 
      n}]], Null], GraphHighlight -> Table[i, {i, 1, n}], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
 , {n, 1, 20, 1}]
```

If I draw this system on the *Mathematica* from n=1 to n=20 , graph representation is shown such as

[image: ![![enter image description here]

I was expecting some kind of pattern as I increase the n value. Sadly, it just shows complicated graph, and I do not see any pattern as I increase n value from the graph generated from *Mathematica*.

Do you think that I can find any pattern from the graph representation using *Mathematica*?

Comment: Try a different `GraphLayout`. `"StarEmbedding"` shows a pattern although I don't know what it means.

Comment: Also look at the `AjdacencyMatrix` of your graph. Try `Graph[...]AdjacencyMatrix // MatrixPlot`. You'll see a distinct pattern there, showing the evolution of two clusters bridged by an initial set of nodes.

Comment: Also look at `ListPlot@VertexDegree@Graph[...]`

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you! I think GraphLayout really helps me to see the pattern.

Comment: What type of system is this coming from? It looks vaguely like a reactive potential, but not quite.

Comment: also `GraphLayout->"BipartiteEmbedding"` ?

Comment: @b3m2a1 If you post the comment you wrote as an answer, I will accept it. Please do it for me!

Comment: @SaesunKim happy to do so

Comment: @kglr I really like that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you can see these patterns three ways:

The first is using `GraphLayout -> "StarEmbedding"`, e.g. in:

```
Graph[
 Flatten[
  Table[
   If[i <= n && j <= n + 1 - i, i <-> n + j, Nothing],
   {i, 1, 2 n},
   {j, 1, n}
   ]
  ],
 GraphHighlight -> Table[i, {i, 1, n}],
 VertexLabels -> "Name",
 GraphLayout -> "StarEmbedding"
 ]
```

This gives you:

[image]

where you see two groups evolve or something like that.

The second option is to view the [`AdjacencyMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyMatrix.html) directly, via:

```
MatrixPlot@AdjacencyMatrix@
  Flatten[
   Table[
    If[i <= n && j <= n + 1 - i, i <-> n + j, Nothing],
    {i, 1, 2 n},
    {j, 1, n}
    ]
   ]
```

This gives:

[image]

A final way to see this evolution is plotting the [`VertexDegree`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexDegree.html) of the vertices (helpfully they're indexed so we don't need to extract the `VertexList` to `Thread` into the degrees). This is done via:

```
ListPlot@VertexDegree@
  Flatten[
   Table[
    If[i <= n && j <= n + 1 - i, i <-> n + j, Nothing],
    {i, 1, 2 n},
    {j, 1, n}
    ]
   ]
```

And then you get:

[image]

All these show the evolution of the distinct groups

Comment: Wow!  Excellent!

Answer (score 4):

Since we have a bipartite graph for every `n`

```
And @@ Table[BipartiteGraphQ @ Graph[Flatten[Table[
   If[i <= n && j <= n + 1 - i, i <-> (n + j), ## &[]], {i, 1, 2 n}, {j, 1, n}]]], 
  {n, 1, 20}]
```

> True

we can use `Graphlayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"` which reveals a nice pattern with the first `n` and the last `n` vertices sorted by vertex degree:

```
frames1 = Table[Graph[Flatten[Table[
   If[i <= n && j <= n + 1 - i, i <-> (n + j), ## &[]], {i, 1, 2 n}, {j, 1, n}]],
    GraphHighlight -> Table[i, {i, 1, n}], 
    VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10, 
    ImageSize -> {300, 300}, GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"],
  {n, 1, 20}];
Export["graph.gif", frames1]
```

[image]

If we use the first argument of `Graph` to have the vertices in a particular order, using b3m2a1'a idea of `MatrixPlot`ting the `AdjacencyMatrix` gives a simpler pattern:

```
frames2 = Table[MatrixPlot[AdjacencyMatrix@
     Graph[Join[Range@n, Reverse[Range[n + 1, 2 n]]], 
      Flatten[Table[If[i <= n && j <= n + 1 - i, i <-> (n + j), ## &[]],
        {i, 1, 2 n}, {j, 1, n}]]]], {n, 1, 20}];
Export["matrixplot.gif", frames2]
```

[image]

Similarly for the `ListLinePlot` of `VertexDegree`s:

```
frames3 = Table[vertices = Join[Range@n, Reverse[Range[n + 1, 2 n]]]; 
   ListLinePlot[MapIndexed[Labeled[{Rescale[#2[[1]], {1, 2 n}, {-n, n}], #}, 
      vertices[[#2[[1]]]], If[#2[[1]] <= n, Before, After]] &, VertexDegree @ #] &@
     Graph[vertices, Flatten[Table[If[i <= n && j <= n + 1 - i, i <-> (n + j), ## &[]], 
       {i, 1, 2 n}, {j, 1, n}]]], 
     PlotRange -> {{-22, 22}, {0, 21}}, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Medium],
     AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, Frame -> False, 
     Mesh -> {Join @@ (Thread /@ {{-#, Red}, {#, Blue}}) &@ Range[2 n + 1]}],
   {n, 1, 20}];
Export["llplot.gif", frames3]
```

[image]

Comment: Your second argument is probably somewhere where you wanted `Animate`? You can also export a `List` of objects as an animated GIF.

Comment: @b3m2a1, I  use ScreenToGif  (to edit size/ frame rate to stay within the 2mb limit) for gifs to post on this site, and `Clock` trick i find convenient  to get an animation without controls.

Comment: Okay. I figured it was a screen capture given the mild joltiness of the thing. Just thought it might be useful for the GIF smoothing here :)

Comment: @b3m2a1, thanks for the suggestion; updated with a smoother version.

Comment: Very nice. I prefer your plots to mine.